# what's the difference between "of" and "being" modifier?

Tags: modifiers

I found a sentence as the following:

> we have the prerequisites `being` algorithms for NLP that's not absolutely required but they will be expecting that you have at least some background here.

does the "being algorithms" mean that all prerequisites are algorithms for NLP?

can `being` be replaced with `of`? is there any difference between `prerequisites being algorithms` and `prerequisites of algorithms`?

Comment: It's hard to understand this statement. The first section appears to be saying: We have the prerequisites; these are algorithms for NLP.  The clause stating **that's not absolutely required** is unclear as to what is not required.  No, you can't replace **being** with **of**. The sense here is **....prerequisites, these being algorithms.....**